# Colons after labels; any accessibility concerns?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

I like having a colon after labels but for form-building components I like not having to specify them. Thus I have CSS like this:

```
label::after {
  content: ':';
}
```

This works fine, but my puppeteer scripts, which use aria selectors, are not finding inputs that are labeled like that due to the colon showing up in the accessible names. For example, given this:

```
<label for="first-name">First name</label><input id="first-name" type="text" />
```

The selector `aria/First name` fails to find the input.

I can add a `:` to the aria selector, but that's annoying, and I'm not sure if the colon ends up as noise to those using screen readers and this is misplaced worry or if there's a cleaner way to do this where the colon shows up for sighted readers but is invisible to screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround while typing the question. Apparently alt text for content can be specified, so this works to show a ":" but render it invisible to the accessibility tree. The `content` property is repeated to catch browsers that don't support this syntax. This seems to be setting the accessible name of labeled inputs to not include the `:`.

```
label::after {
  content: ':';
  content: ':' / '';
}
```

Comment: Note that on browsers that don't support the CSS alt text and thus falling back on your "plain" `content` property, you're back to the original problem that the colon will be part of the accessible name.  In your case it might not matter since you're running puppeteer on Chrome and Chrome supports the alt text.  On Firefox, you'll still get the colon in the a11y name but you're not running puppeteer there.  But a screen reader will announce the colon as part of the label (depending on the verbosity setting of the screen reader).

Answer (score 0):

Using the *alt* feature of `CSS:content` is creative but mainly works on Chrome (and Edge, since it's chromium).  Firefox and Safari don't support it (yet) and in fact it makes the `content` property invalid on those browsers so your `content` is not displayed at all.

On Chrome, it's not exactly fully supported either.  The alt text is honored for `url` content:

```
label::after {
  content: url(image.gif) / "my alt text";
}
```

meaning that when you navigate with a screen reader to the label, or the input associated with that label, you'll hear the alt text.

But for *text* `content`, the alt text is not used.  It treats **all** alt text as NULL.

```
label::after {
  content: "hello" / "my alt text"; 
}
label::after {
  content: "hello" / ""; 
}
```

Both of these examples cause the `content` to **not** be used in the accessible name calculation (Step 2.F.ii in https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2), which gives you what you want for puppeteer - an ARIA selector that doesn't have the content.

An alternative way to do this that is supported on all browsers is to have your `content` on an element with `aria-hidden="true"`.

```
<style>
.foo::after {
  content: ':';
}
<style>

<label for="first-name">First name<span class="foo" aria-hidden="true"></span></label>
<input id="first-name" type="text" />
```

Comment: I updated my answer below; I did find a workaround for that `content` property approach not working on Firefox, and it seems to work for FF and Chromium now. I checked the accessible name in both of those browsers and it seems to be correct.

Wouldn't `aria-hidden="true"` on the label cause the input to not be labeled?

Comment: You wouldn't want `aria-hidden` on the `<label>` itself.  It's on the `<span>` inside the label.

Comment: Gotcha, missed that